# Does Lateral View explode not work from within hivecontext in spark

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

Question is does lateral view explode not work from within hiveContext in spark shell. Below is the sample table & sample spark code.
Expected output from spark frame "vasOtherDF" is 6 but it gives 8.

Hive Table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `aa`(
`col1` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
'hdfs://nn1001.dev:8020/tmp/aa'
```

Sample Data:

```
aaa|qq|ww|dd
aaa
aaa|bbb
ccc
```

Hive Outputs:

```
select count(distinct vother) as vothers from aa LATERAL VIEW explode(split(col1,'\\|')) a as vother;
6

select distinct vother as vothers from rafm.aa LATERAL VIEW explode(split(col1,'\\|')) a as vother;

aaa
bbb
ccc
dd
qq
ww
```

Spark Outputs:

```
val vasOtherDF = hiveContext.sql("select count(distinct vother) as vothers from aa LATERAL VIEW explode(split(col1,'\\|')) a as vother")
output: 8

select distinct vother as vothers from rafm.aa LATERAL VIEW explode(split(col1,'\\|')) a as vother;
aaa
bbb
ccc
dd
qq
ww


val vasOtherDF = hiveContext.sql("select distinct vother as vothers from aa LATERAL VIEW explode(split(col1,'\\|')) a as vother")
scala> vasOtherDF.show
+-------+
|vothers|
+-------+
|      a|
|      b|
|      c|
|      d|
|      q|
|      w|
|      ||
|       |
+-------+
```

Comment: what does the output of `split` show?

Comment: added same in question

Comment: use `\\\\|` 4 backslashes to escape `|`

Comment: Thanks Vamsi Prabhala!
adding 4 backlashes works.